# How to make buttermilk at home?

Tags: milk, buttermilk

A recipe calls for buttermilk but I don’t want to go to the store just for that. Can I make my own

Comment: what is your recipe? look at the link @mattm posted for alternatives to buttermilk

Answer (score -1):

Yes you can, if you have full fat cream.

The process is straightforward but a little time-consuming, and it will be much faster to just go buy a bottle of buttermilk.

Buttermilk is just the residual liquid of butter-making (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buttermilk): you have your cream, better if cultured, and you whip it (a food processor will do it) until the solids thicken into butter.

The liquid that remains is buttermilk

Comment: Actually no, this is the old meaning of buttermilk. Nowadays people use the word for something different, and using this traditional buttermilk will ruin most modern recipes.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. In fact here in South of Europe buttermilk does not exist commercially, so I referred to traditional buttermilk, but did not consider that this is mostly an US/UK-centric community. Also, and for that I am not sorry, I incite everybody to make things from scratch, and I guess you cannot reproduce commercial buttermilk at home (at least not easily)

Comment: You can certainly reproduce it - it is just a cultured product, so it's as easy as making yogurt. You just need the right starter and to know the process, I think it takes much lower temperature than yogurt cultures.

Comment: I guess you can culture it starting with some store-bought buttermilk...  again I am biased by my geographical context, where it is not available